# Animated constraint change layoutIfNeeded slow

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewanimation, autolayout

I'm trying to animate a my `ADBannerView` on and off screen using autolayout. Pre-autolayout (setting frame and animating) everything worked fine. Now I have the following code and it runs on `viewDidLoad` to make sure the ad banner if off the screen.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kADAnimationDuration
                 animations:^{
                     _addBannerDistanceFromBottomConstraint.constant = 32;
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];    
}];
```

This code work, but it is *slow*. `layoutIfNeeded` is taking a long time (relatively) and causes poor performance. Removing the line makes everything nice and fast, but the animation doesn't work.

The question is... why is this so slow/how do I speed it up?

**Edit:** My UI is fairly significant and I thought laying out everything might be the cause, so I tried creating a simple `UIView` and putting my banner in there as a `subview`, then I only needed to call `layoutIfNeeded` on that `subview` with 1 item in it. No change in performance though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an app with the `ADBannerView` and nothing else. Same problem existing. I submitted to Apple as a bug and got "duplicate" so I guess it's a known issue.

As a workaround I'm starting with the ad banner off the screen and moving on the screen only when I get a valid ad. While it's slightly more annoying to work with in the storyboard, the user won't notice the difference and it prevents the slow down.

**Edit:** I've been working more with auto layout and I've come to a unfortunate conclusion which I seem to share with Matt Neuburg. In bit he wrote titled "[auto layout slow on iOS](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/323960-auto-layout-slow-on-ios.html)" he said:

> It's a pity, but auto layout is slow on iOS.

It pretty much has summed up several issues I've been having converting one of my apps to auto layout. The performance is simply not there. The example Matt gives in his post has auto-layout taking 5 times longer to accomplish the same task.

For now, I guess I'll be avoiding auto layout for anything complicated enough for auto layout to be useful.

**Edit:** `iOS 8` is in beta and constraints have gotten significantly faster. There is still when using a lot (50+) especially on older devices but from testing so far the formerly 2 second delay I was getting has been reduced to about 0.4 seconds. With this change constraints may have been sped up enough to be viable for some constraint heavy view work.

Comment: Thanks for link to Matt's post. I've given up on autolayout too for the same reason. Too slow.

Answer (score 1):

One problem might be doing this in viewDidLoad, where view parameters haven't been set up yet, though, I don't know why that would make it slow. You might try it in viewDidAppear instead. Also, according to what I saw in the WWDC 2012 auto layout sessions, you should add the constraint (or modify the constant as you're doing) outside the animation block, not inside. Try moving it above the animation block.

Comment: Your right about changing the constraint in the animation block. I moved it out, but no effect at all. The reason I call an animation block `viewDidLoad` is simply because it's the same method which gets called when the `ADBannerView` fails to load. I tried moving it to `viewDidAppear` and the behavior is identical.

Comment: If don't have any experience with ADBannerView -- is it doing downloads from a server? I've certainly never seen anything like the kind of slowdown you're seeing when animating constraints.

Comment: Yes, Ad banners download from the server. They have a delegate methods which are basically "success" and "fail" calls. Fail, you animate ad out. Success you animate it in. I think my next test is going to be trying the animate with a simple `UIView`. Could it be the the `AdBannerView` itself which is causing the slowdown in the constraint animation? (none of my other constraints have any issue animating).

Comment: @DBD, I think it probably is an AdBannerView problem -- I haven't had any problems either with other types of views.